# Cross-Platform alternative to expr length

Tags: bash, script

When running some BASH scripts I had in my Linux box I noticed that `expr length` gives syntax error.

Manual pages doesn't seems to include any information about the length operator. Is it missing in Mac OS X?

What other cross-platform alternative can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `expr length 'keyword'` you can use awk. An example would look like this `echo 'keyword' | awk '{ print length }'`

```
bounty:~ napcae$ echo 'keyword' | awk '{ print length }'  
7
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you share the portion of the script that does not work on your Mac OS X? `expr`in general adheres to `IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (POSIX.1)` and is available on all Unix Systems with the same semantics.

If you share some more information regarding your bash script, I am sure we can help. Your posted example of `expr length`, albeit being pretty useless per se, runs perfectly fine in my Mac OS X Mavericks Shell:

```
~$ expr length
length
```

Not sure what you have tried to achieve, but I could imagine your were trying to get the length of a string?

```
~$ a="non sequitur"
~$ expr \( "X$a" : ".*" \) - 1
12
~$ echo ${#a}
12
```

With regard to cross-platform, it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish with your bash script. Bash by itself is pretty cross-platform.